# Where is the serialized user session stored with Memcache as a session handler? And how to read/write into the serialized data?

Tags: php, session, memcached, joomla3.0

i am trying to communicate with Memcache as a session handler for Joomla. Following the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php) bottom example i have registered memcache a session handler. As soon as a user loads the Joomla site its session id together with other user data is stored into the Joomla database. But now i don't know how to get hands on Memcache to read the serialized session data like can be done with XCache using `xcache_get($sessionid)` As soon as i create a new Memcache instance as can be seen in the docs top example the session entry is removed from the database. But the session yet exists. This is quite confusing to me. I required to access (read/write) the serialized user session. How can i fetch/set it from the PHP session handler?

Comment: what version of joomla is this? In any case you can usually access the session itself via the $_SESSION super global, if not via Joomla's session implementation. Accessing sessions directly is not the best idea.

Comment: I'm referring to Joomla 3.2. Believe me, i know that direct manipulation is no good idea, but i am working to develop a [patch for an issue](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3126) and missing to get hands on Memcache to adopt the working code for other session handlers to the Memcache(d) handler(s)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the equivalent you are looking for is something like this:

Getting the session:

```
$session = $memcache->get($sessionId);
```

Setting the session:

```
$memcache->set(
    'sessionprefix:'.$sessionId,    // the session id.
    $session,           // the actual session itself
    false,              // set to true to use compression
    $expire,            // expiration in second
);
```

I have not used memcache very much but I have read that people usually use a prefix in the key to separate the different types of objects (this is also a common practice with redis, a similar data store). I have used 'sessionprefix:' here but I am sure Joomla has their own specific prefix.

Comment: Yes, i already supposed that from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816128/change-serialization-functions-in-php-for-memcached). But the question left unanswered is: "Where does the variable $memcache relate to?" It is no Global. As stated i tried to relate it to a new Memcache instance, which failed to work as intended. I suppose this created a second Memcache instance. The prefix shouldn't be a problem. The main problem is to find out where the serialized data resides so i can load, unserialize, process and store it back it for the changes to take affect.

Comment: The data in memcache resides in the memory of a running memcache server (therefor the name). The memcache API (or the protocol) is the only way to modify it. Check out http://blog.softlayer.com/2012/meet-memcached-a-developers-best-friend and http://memcached.org/about for a lengthier explanation.

Comment: This is nothing new to me. But you're mixing up the data cache and the session cache. While the data cache is explicitely instanciated first before one can use it, it is not when registering it as a PHP session.handler via ini_set(). Check the linked PHP doc in my initial post. Latter gives no reference to it in return, which is why i stuck to request the serialized session data from it. Also, your kindly linked pages do all together refer to another accelerator - MemcachD - (note the trailing D) which is not what i refer to. My problem refers to Memcache - without the trailing D.

Comment: It seems like both of them access the same storage but are different APIs: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php. From what I can gather the memcache extension is specific to PHP and memcached uses libmemcached.